# to give 'view more' option for larger contents (like larger comments)- bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap collapse plugin, how to give 'view more' option for larger content (like in some websites they given for larger comments)?

How to fix the maximum height of the div and make additional contents hidden?
When user clicks the view more option it will show all the full content. How can I code for this?

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I know only how to use collapse in bootstrap, not more than that. I'm just a beginner.